# Why does Entity Framework return ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> for a stored procedure which returns a Not Null column?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a simple stored procedure which returns a primary key from a table (so it is NOT NULL).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetActiveUsers
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Active=1
END
```

When I create the function in EF 4.0, and select it to return a collection if Int32 in the designer window, it creates the stored procedure:

```
ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> spGetActiveUsers();
```

But it can't ever return a NULL value in the collection.  So to get the non-nullable list of ints, I would have to call:

```
int[] results = context.spGetActiveUsers().Select(u => u.Value).ToArray();
```

This doesn't seem right: shouldn't it know it can't contain null values?

Answer (score 0):

because no class for your stored procedure is created when you update edmx and this causes your stored procedure return type of int value not the type of dataa

Comment: But I want it to return Int values and not a class.  But instead it is returning int? values.

Answer (score 0):

Force making your return scalar value from stored procedure to NOT NULL in all case.

I mean, e.g

DECLARE @ReturnScalar INT
--Your Stored Procedure Here--
RETURN ISNULL(@ReturnScalar,0)

Above statement ensures that you never return null and edmx will consider this as a not null

Thanks